# MATCH_PARENT if sibling view is larger, WRAP_CONTENT if sibling view is smaller

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two views in a layout.
I'll call them `View A` and `View B` respectively.

```
┌──────┐
│┌─┐┌─┐│
││A││B││
│└─┘└─┘│
└──────┘
```

The height of parent layout (which includes `View A` and `View B`) is `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Here, the height of `View B` is `WRAP_CONTENT`. That is, its height can be changed with respect to its content.

What I want to do is

1. Set `View A`'s height to `View B`'s height if `View A`'s content is shorter than `View B`'s content.
2. Set `View A`'s height to its own content's height if `View A`'s content is taller than `View B`'s content.

So,

① If content of `View B` is taller, then `View A`'s height is set to `View B`'s height.

```
       ┌──────┐      ┌──────┐
       │┌─┐┌─┐│      │┌─┐┌─┐│
       ││ ││ ││      ││A││ ││
I want ││A││B││, not │└─┘│B││.
       ││ ││ ││      │   │ ││
       │└─┘└─┘│      │   └─┘│
       └──────┘      └──────┘
```

② If content of `View B` is shorter, then `View A`'s height is `View A`'s own conent's height.

```
       ┌──────┐      ┌──────┐
       │┌─┐┌─┐│      │┌─┐┌─┐│
       ││ ││B││      ││A││B││
I want ││A│└─┘│, not │└─┘└─┘│.
       ││ │   │      └──────┘
       │└─┘   │
       └──────┘
```

If the parent is `LinearLayout (Horizontal)`, setting `View A`'s height to `WRAP_CONTENT` violates case 1, and setting `View A`'s height to `MATCH_PARENT` violates case 2.

If the parent is `RelativeLayout`, setting `View A` to align both its parent's top and bottom violates `RelativeLayout`'s condition: 
`Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's different ways to go about this, for example by creating your own custom `ViewGroup`, probably based on a horizontal `LinearLayout`. However, I recon that the most straightforward solution would be to dynamically set the requirements at runtime.

Consider the following layout with just two `TextView`s in a horizontal `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="One line" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Two\nlines"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Both wrap their height, which basically matches up to your first requirement.

Now requirement 2: for demonstration purposes, I've broken the second `TextView`'s text up into two lines, in order to make it taller than the first one. To make the first `TextView` match it's height, all you have to do is this:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
final TextView first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first);
final TextView second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second);

container.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        int h1 = first.getMeasuredHeight();
        int h2 = second.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h1 < h2) first.getLayoutParams().height = h2;

    }
});
```

The 'trick' is to post to the view's queue, ensuring the logic will not get executed until the children have been measured and have a valid height. For requirement 2, the height of the first view will only have to be changed if the second view is taller, which is exactly what the part in the `run()` method does.

Comment: Isn't there a xml way to do this? Otherwise I will have to do this inside my adapter because I want to do something like this inside a dynamically filled list.

Comment: @BartBurg: A custom `ViewGroup` would probably be the most optimal solution. Extending `LinearLayout` would be a good start and - depending on your specific use case - all you may need to do is override `onMeasure()` to take into account the criteria outlined above.

Comment: It causes an animation effect, which may be undesirable. A custom ViewGroup sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa: Any chance you have `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` set or used `setLayoutTransition()` on the container view (see also [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html))? Without those, the height changing dynamically shouldn't really be noticeable. Still, the solution above isn't ideal, and a custom `ViewGroup` is really the way to go. If I can find the time, I'll have a quick go at it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved very easily, from just the axml.

Keep the parent layout's height as wrap_content and set every child view's height to be match_parent. This will cause the parent layout's height to wrap to the highest child, and every child view's height to stretch to the parents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="text" />
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="More\ntext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the dimensions of the views programmatically using layout params. Assuming that you are using a LinearLayout to hold the views this is what you would do:

```
//the views are called a and b
LinearLayout.LayoutParams aParams = a.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams bParams = b.getLayoutParams();
int aWidth = aParams.width;
int aHeight = aParams.height;
int bWidth = bParams.width;
int bHeight = bParams.height;
if (aHeight >= bHeight) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    a.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(aWidth, bHeight));
}
```

When you set their heights originally keep them as wrap_content in the xml, prior to this modification.