# Android: make ImageView match the height of another view

Tags: android, layout, imageview, height, android-linearlayout

I have a problem designing a layout of an application. This is what I'm trying to get:

```
=========================================================
|  =============   ================   ================  |
|  |           |   | LinearLayout |   | LinearLayout |  |
|  |           |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  |           |   | | TextView | |   | | TextView | |  |
|  | ImageView |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  |           |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  |           |   | | TextView | |   | | TextView | |  |
|  |           |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  |           |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  |           |   | | TextView | |   | | TextView | |  |
|  |           |   | ============ |   | ============ |  |
|  =============   ================   ================  |
=========================================================
```

This is whay I've done so far (I've removed ids an another stuff for the sake of clarity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that I want to use high resolution images and scale them down to match the the highest of the linearlayouts next to it. My idea is to make android scale down the image on devices with low dpi, therefore using the same images and layout for all the platforms.

As it is now, the main container height gets as big as the image height. What I want is the main container height to be the same as the "tallest" linearlayout and force the imageview to scale down in order to fit the main container.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

PD: Excuse my english! :$

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATCH\_PARENT if sibling view is larger, WRAP\_CONTENT if sibling view is smaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119173/match-parent-if-sibling-view-is-larger-wrap-content-if-sibling-view-is-smaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heights widths and all those stuffs of all the views are measured in onMeasure() of the activity.. A notice worthy point is, onMeasure() of any view executes just before the onDraw() and can be executed n-number of times. So, it is good to calculate the width and height of your LinearLayout in its onMeasure().

Comment: Despite your answer being the most incomplete, it was the one that was most helpful. The other answers imporse restrictions to the widths that I didn't ask for. Based on your answer, I guess I could create a custom layout that fixes its height based on another height.

So, albeit being not the best answer, I'm still chosing yours as the accepted answer. Thanks Abhishek Shukla!

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_linearlayout);

    int llHeight = ll.getHeight();

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageview);

    LayoutParams ivParams = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageview)).getLayoutParams();

    ivParams.height = llHeight;

    iv.setLayoutParams(ivParams );
```

Comment: Excuse me. But that wouldn't give me three views with the same width? The LinearLayout is orientation horizontal, not vertical. I want the imageview to have the same height of the linearlayouts next to it. But I don't want to modify the widths.

Comment: @Gonzalo Brusco for that u have to get the linear-layout height dynamically and then set the image view height.

Comment: I though about that. But if I go that route, I would have to recalculate the imageview on screen rotation. I'm just hoping there's an easy solution using just xml. Something like "set parent height as this child height and ignore the other childs" Thank you anyway!!

Comment: @Gonzalo Brusco ok..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to implements the below code.

See the below image.

[image: Here is the Screen shot of below code]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="@drawable/black"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.15">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Linear Layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.15">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Linear Layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could have used a better image to demonstrate... Or at least change the background to an opposite colour.